# XCode 9 - Error while importing #import <objc/runtime.h> - for Simulator Only

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode9, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to import #import  & it gives me below error:

***Declaration of 'objc_property_t' must be imported from module 'ObjectiveC.runtime' before it is required***

Here is the code:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#if TARGET_IPHONE_SIMULATOR
#import <objc/objc-runtime.h>
#else
#import <objc/runtime.h>
#import <objc/message.h>
#endif
```

Please Note: For Device, it's compiled successfully. It generates an error for Simulator only. This happens since I started using XCode 9. For XCode 8 it was working fine.

Comment: Does the deployment target or simulator you select to run make a difference?

Comment: No. It doesn't make difference. Same error persists.

Comment: Could also be a bug, try the 11.1 beta SDK...

Comment: If you're building WebKit and seeing this kind of error, run the embedded development script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in iOS 11, objc-runtime.h has been removed.

[image]

You need to either remove if macro or import , inside it.

Comment: Removed if macro